# Adding a "Shared" module to Android app with App Engine Endpoint backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I'm diving into Android development and getting a bit hung up trying to avoid duplicating code.

I'm using Android Studio and have a project with two modules - the app itself, and the GAE endpoint backend.

I want to be able to send objects between the two modules so the approach I'm taking is creating a "shared" module and adding a dependency to it in both the app and the backend modules.  In this module I place my shared classes, and when I need to send them back and forth I'm using GSON.

I am not getting any errors until I attempt to debug the app, where the backend build fails with:
"Error: package [shared lib namespace] does not exist".

Can anyone describe or point me to an example of how to share code between the app and backend?

Thanks

Comment: Good question - I too would like to have some guidelines here. How did you end up going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to share the code between the server backend and client and that's exactly what I am thinking to do. Here is my solution.  (I assume you are using Android studio with Gradle support)

1. create a new module (File -> New Module), choose type Java module and name the project to whatever you prefer. In my case, I name it to `utils`
2. add this module to the dependency of both client and backend project

for client project

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile project(':utils')
}
```

for backend project

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.3'
    compile project(':utils')
}
```

Comment: I tried this a couple of times and everything would look great until I tried to compile - at which point one of the projects would complain that it couldn't find code located in 'utils'.  I've changed up the design a bit since then as I realized there were some architectural flaws with the direction I was heading.  However I'm sure I'll have to tackle this again in the future so I will keep this answer in mind.

Comment: Also I should note that since I tried and had issues, Android Studio has had major updates.

Comment: If the compiler complains about module not found, your best chance is to check the `settings.gradle` in the project and make sure the module is configured with the right path, especially when u import the module from somewhere outside the project directory.

Comment: I had already a project shared like your answer, but now I want to add a new appengine project and use some included tools like gson. But I want to use this gson in the android app, and in this case I exceed the 64K methods limit. (I could use multidex, I know, but I am importing the whole appengine depencency for just Gson. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way is to share source code. This is because I usually share code that naturally belongs to one of the existing projects.

To share source code, add the following in your build.gradle.

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../module2/shared'
}
```

NOTE: For the Android module, the above should be inside the android{} method.